# Consumer/Producer "timely" queue

Tags: python, priority-queue, anti-patterns

I've implemented an consumer/producer priority queue, where the priority is actually a time stamp representing when the item should be delivered.  It works pretty well but I would like to know if any one has a better idea to implement this or comments about the current implementation.

The code is in Python.  A single thread is created to wake up waiting consumers on time.  I know this is an anti-pattern to create a thread in a library but I couldn't devise another method.

Here is the code:

```
import collections
import heapq
import threading
import time

class TimelyQueue(threading.Thread):
    """
    Implements a similar but stripped down interface of Queue which
    delivers items on time only.
    """

    class Locker:
        def __init__(self, lock):
            self.l = lock
        def __enter__(self):
            self.l.acquire()
            return self.l
        def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
            self.l.release()

    # Optimization to avoid wasting CPU cycles when something
    # is about to happen in less than 5 ms.
    _RESOLUTION = 0.005

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.queue = []
        self.triggered = collections.deque()
        self.putcond = threading.Condition()
        self.getcond = threading.Condition()
        # Optimization to avoid waking the thread uselessly.
        self.putwaketime = 0

    def put(self, when, item):
        with self.Locker(self.putcond):
            heapq.heappush(self.queue, (when, item))
            if when < self.putwaketime or self.putwaketime == 0:
                self.putcond.notify()

    def get(self, timeout=None):
        with self.Locker(self.getcond):
            if len(self.triggered) > 0:
                when, item = self.triggered.popleft()
                return item
                self.getcond.wait(timeout)
            try:
                when, item = self.triggered.popleft()
            except IndexError:
                return None
            return item

    def qsize(self):
        with self.Locker(self.putcond):
            return len(self.queue)

    def run(self):
        with self.Locker(self.putcond):
            maxwait = None
            while True:
                curtime = time.time()
                try:
                    when, item = self.queue[0]
                    maxwait = when - curtime
                    self.putwaketime = when
                except IndexError:
                    maxwait = None
                    self.putwaketime = 0
                self.putcond.wait(maxwait)

                curtime = time.time()
                while True:
                    # Don't dequeue now, we are not sure to use it yet.
                    try:
                        when, item = self.queue[0]
                    except IndexError:
                        break
                    if when > curtime + self._RESOLUTION:
                        break

                    self.triggered.append(heapq.heappop(self.queue))
                if len(self.triggered) > 0:
                    with self.Locker(self.getcond):
                        self.getcond.notify()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = TimelyQueue()
    q.start()

    N = 50000
    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(N):
        q.put(time.time() + 2, i)
    dt = time.time() - t0
    print "put done in %.3fs (%.2f put/sec)" % (dt, N / dt)
    t0 = time.time()
    i = 0
    while i < N:
        a = q.get(3)
        if i == 0:
            dt = time.time() - t0
            print "start get after %.3fs" % dt
            t0 = time.time()
        i += 1
    dt = time.time() - t0
    print "get done in %.3fs (%.2f get/sec)" % (dt, N / dt)
```

Comment: I might make the presence of the thread less explicit, so the object looks like a `Queue` rather than a `Thread`. Also, why are you constructing a `Locker` context manager around the `Condition`? See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement).

Comment: @abarnert Good idea for the thread, I'll create it in the constructor.  Regrding the `Locker` I think I've never read the documentation that far :).  Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Is this meant to be a single-consumer implementation? If not, you might want to consider `notifyAll`, because there could be multiple entries that have come due at once. More importantly, you probably want multi-threaded unit tests.

Comment: @abarnert No, multiple consumers.  You are right this is a bug.  I've written a multi-threaded test unit externally but it was too big to inline in the file and the code was so ugly I was ashamed to publish it.

Comment: One last not-quite-on-topic comment: You may want to look over the source for [Queue.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/Queue.py) and the unit tests for it in the standard library, just to make sure you didn't miss anything important. And look at whether you can actually build this as a wrapper around `Queue` (like the standard `PriorityQueue`) instead of from scratch, so you can get some extra functionality for free (mainly `maxsize`, which is painful to get right)—although as always, keep YAGNI in mind; it may not be worth it.

Comment: Well, for the implementation, not for the unit tests, I've already looked at it actually.  I wanted to derive Queue at first but I would have needed to rewrite put() and get() methods anyway so I went for a stripped down interface.  I could

Comment: With this regard, if we wanted a compatible interface with `Queue`, going for duck typing would be rather easier than inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you really need the background thread for here is a timer to kick the waiters when it runs out, right?

First, you could implement that with [`threading.Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects) instead of an explicit background thread. But, while that might be simpler, it won't really solve the problem that you're creating a thread behind the user's back, whether they want it or not. Also, with `threading.Timer`, you're actually spinning off a new thread every time you restart the timer, which may be a performance problem. (You only have one at a time, but still, starting and stopping threads isn't free.)

If you look around PyPI modules, ActiveState recipes, and various frameworks, there are many implementations that let you run multiple timers on a single background thread. That would solve your problem.

But that still isn't a perfect solution. For example, let's say my app needs 20 `TimelyQueue` objects--or a `TimelyQueue` plus 19 other things that all need timers. I'd still end up with 20 threads. Or, let's say I'm building a socket server or a GUI app (the two most obvious use cases for your `TimelyQueue`; I can implement a timer on top of my event loop (or, most likely, just use a timer that comes with the framework), so why should I need a thread at all?

The way out of that is to offer a hook to supply any timer factory:

```
def __init__(self, timerfactory = threading.Timer):
    self.timerfactory = timerfactory
    ...
```

Now, when you need to adjust the timer:

```
if when < self.waketime:
    self.timer.cancel()
    self.timer = self.timerfactory(when - now(), self.timercallback)
    self.waketime = when
```

For quick & dirty use cases, this would be good enough out of the box. But if I'm, e.g., using [`twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/core/howto/time.html), I can just use `TimelyQueue(twisted.reactor.callLater)`, and now the queue's timers go through the `twisted` event loop. Or, if I've got a multi-timers-one-thread implementation I'm using elsewhere, `TimelyQueue(multiTimer.add)`, and now the queue's timers go on the same thread as all of my other timers.

If you wanted to, you could supply a better default than `threading.Timer`, but really, I think most people who need something better than `threading.Timer` will be able to provide something that's better for their particular app than whatever you provide.

Of course not every timer implementation has the same API as `threading.Timer`--although you'd be surprised how many of them do. But it's not that hard to write an adapter, if you've got a timer you want to use with `TimelyQueue` but it has the wrong interface. For example, if I'm building a PyQt4/PySide app, [`QTimer`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtimer.html) doesn't have a `cancel` method, and takes ms instead of seconds, so I'd have to do something like this:

```
class AdaptedQTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, timeout, callback):
        self.timer = QTimer.singleShot(timeout * 1000, callback)
    def cancel(self):
        self.timer.stop()

q = TimelyQueue(AdaptedQTimer)
```

Or, if I wanted to integrate the queue into a `QObject` more directly, I could wrap up `QObject.startTimer()` and have my `timerEvent(self)` method call the callback.

Once you're considering adapters, one last idea. I don't think this is worth it, but it might be worth considering. If your timer took a timestamp rather than a timedelta, and has an `adjust` method rather than/instead of a `cancel`, and held its own `waketime`, your `TimelyQueue` implementation could be simpler, and possibly more efficient. In `put`, you've got something like this:

```
if self.timer is None:
    self.timer = self.timerfactory(when)
elif when < self.timer.waketime:
    self.timer.adjust(when)
```

Of course most timers don't provide this interface. But if someone has one, or is willing to craft one, they can get the benefits. And for everyone else, you can provide a simple adapter that turns a `threading.Timer`-style timer into the kind you need, something like:

```
def timerFactoryAdapter(threadingStyleTimerFactory):
    class TimerFactory(object):
        def __init__(self, timestamp, callback):
            self.timer = threadingStyleTimerFactory(timestamp - now(), callback)
            self.callback = callback
        def cancel(self):
            return self.timer.cancel()
        def adjust(self, timestamp):
            self.timer.cancel()
            self.timer = threadingStyleTimerFactory(timestamp - now(), self.callback)
```

Comment: That solution sounds nice but I worry about the cost of creating a thread each time I need to arm a timer.  Wouldn't it be more reasonable to provide my own termination request method that would have to be called by the caller when needed?

Comment: @JeremieLeHen: I'm not sure I understand your question. But let me restate the idea in the answer, and see if it makes more sense that way.

Comment: Actually, now that I re-read your question, I think maybe what you're talking about _is_ a timer factory, and I just didn't get your terminology (and vice-versa). If so, I apologize. If not, and if what I'm saying still doesn't do what you want, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I've implemented what you proposed using the timer factory.  I ran a small benchmark using the version above and the new version using the `threading.Timer` class:

1. First implementation

   - With a default resolution (5 ms, that is everything within a 5 ms window gets fired together), it  achieves about 88k `put()`/sec and 69k `get()`/sec.
   - With a resolution set to 0 ms (no optimization), it achieves about 88k `put()`/sec and 55k `get()`/sec.
2. Second implementation

   - With a default resolution (5 ms), it  achieves about 88k `put()`/sec and 65k `get()`/sec.
   - With a resolution set to 0 ms, it achieves about 88k `put()`/sec and 62k `get()`/sec.

I admit I am surprised the second implementation is faster without the resolution optimization.  It is too late now to investigate.

```
import collections
import heapq
import threading
import time

class TimelyQueue:
    """
    Implements a similar but stripped down interface of Queue which
    delivers items on time only.
    """

    def __init__(self, resolution=5, timerfactory=threading.Timer):
        """
        `resolution' is an optimization to avoid wasting CPU cycles when
        something is about to happen in less than X ms.
        """
        self.resolution = float(resolution) / 1000
        self.timerfactory = timerfactory
        self.queue = []
        self.triggered = collections.deque()
        self.putcond = threading.Condition()
        self.getcond = threading.Condition()
        # Optimization to avoid waking the thread uselessly.
        self.putwaketime = 0
        self.timer = None
        self.terminating = False

    def __arm(self):
        """
        Arm the next timer; putcond must be acquired!
        """
        curtime = time.time()
        when, item = self.queue[0]
        interval = when - curtime
        self.putwaketime = when
        self.timer = self.timerfactory(interval, self.__fire)
        self.timer.start()

    def __fire(self):
        with self.putcond:
            curtime = time.time()
            debug = 0
            while True:
                # Don't dequeue now, we are not sure to use it yet.
                try:
                    when, item = self.queue[0]
                except IndexError:
                    break
                if when > curtime + self.resolution:
                    break

                debug += 1
                self.triggered.append(heapq.heappop(self.queue))
            if len(self.triggered) > 0:
                with self.getcond:
                    self.getcond.notify(len(self.triggered))
            if self.terminating:
                return
            if len(self.queue) > 0:
                self.__arm()

    def put(self, when, item):
        """
        `when' is a Unix time from Epoch.
        """
        with self.putcond:
            heapq.heappush(self.queue, (when, item))
            if when >= self.putwaketime and self.putwaketime != 0:
                return
            # Arm next timer.
            if self.timer is not None:
                self.timer.cancel()
            self.__arm()

    def get(self, timeout=None):
        """
        Timely return the next object on the queue.
        """
        with self.getcond:
            if len(self.triggered) > 0:
                when, item = self.triggered.popleft()
                return item
            self.getcond.wait(timeout)
            try:
                when, item = self.triggered.popleft()
            except IndexError:
                return None
            return item

    def qsize(self):
        """
        Self explanatory.
        """
        with self.putcond:
            return len(self.queue)

    def terminate(self):
        """
        Request the embedded thread to terminate.
        """
        with self.putcond:
            self.terminating = True
            if self.timer is not None:
                self.timer.cancel()
            self.putcond.notifyAll()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = TimelyQueue(0)
    N = 100000
    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(N):
        q.put(time.time() + 2, i)
    dt = time.time() - t0
    print "put done in %.3fs (%.2f put/sec)" % (dt, N / dt)
    t0 = time.time()
    i = 0
    while i < N:
        a = q.get(3)
        if i == 0:
            dt = time.time() - t0
            print "start get after %.3fs" % dt
            t0 = time.time()
        i += 1
    dt = time.time() - t0
    print "get done in %.3fs (%.2f get/sec)" % (dt, N / dt)
    q.terminate()
    # Give change to the thread to exit properly, otherwise we may get
    # a stray interpreter exception.
    time.sleep(0.1)
```